# How to find synergistic effect of 2 exposures in mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model

I am now doing a impact of 2 air pollutants on mental health score decline over 1 year, (2 follow-up, and I am wondering of there are any addictive effect/synergistic effect of two pollutants. As I know it is pretty rare for such methods in targeting air pollutants as they are in high multi-col-linearity. What method in GLM to deal with such issue?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I don't understand your statement about colinearity. However, synergistic effects can be modeled as interactions: Something along the line of `mental_health ~ polutant_1 * polutant_2`. If the interaction estimate is positive, you have evidence for a synergistic effect, and if it is negative you have evidence for a cancelling effect. Is that what you want?

Comment: I am wondering when the two pollutants are highly correlated (like spearman's r >0.7) will that be still possible to use interaction?

Comment: Yes that will be fine. Pairwise correlation does not necessitate colinearity. You could try and calculate a measure for colinearity, like the condition number